# How do I remove billing address from the thank you page?

Tags: php, woocommerce

So I want to remove the billing address from the thank you page. I am using wordpress and have the theme Impreza.

I have targeted the .woocommerce-customer-details and set to display: none; which worked on the google inspector mode but saved and refreshed and it still shows up. And I have checked the woo-commerce template files and found the order-details-customer.php is generating the information. I added a class to remove that section but it still shows up.

[Woocommerce thank you page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRNMB.png)

Comment: have you looked at the specificity of your style compared to the style that is styling said element?

Comment: Can we see some code here? Also, that link gave me a 404. Anyway a code example here is better than an image. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Your woocommerce templates might be overrided from theme. Try checking your theme

Comment: @melvin yes I created an override of the order-details-customer.php since that seems to be the information being pulled into the thankyou.php and added a class to the section containing the whole thing. At first, it was not pulling the override. But yesterday I fixed that and verified under the woocommerce status that it recognizes my override. And I am currently testing. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I created my own override since my theme does not contain the woocommerce folder in it's root. @melvin

Comment: Have you fixed ?@HerodneyEmile

Comment: yes thanks guys I did fix. i created the override and removed the section that had to do with the billing info.

Answer (score -1):

In theme find a folder named woocommerce if not exist then Create folder:

Copy this file

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php
```

and paste it into your active theme directory something like this

```
/wp-content/themes/activetheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php
```

And remove this

```
<ul class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">
    <li class="order">
        <?php _e( 'Order Number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
    </li>
    <li class="date">
        <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></strong>
    </li>
    <li class="total">
        <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
    </li>
    <?php if ( $order->payment_method_title ) : ?>
    <li class="method">
        <?php _e( 'Payment Method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <strong><?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?></strong>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and also remove this

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->payment_method, $order->id ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->id ); ?>
```

Comment: i still want the order info to remain. Just want the billing address removed.

Comment: @HerodneyEmile best way to do this is by modifying the template "order\order-details-customer.php".  Copy this to your theme to override the default layout and remove the billing details.